# Unable to open .storyboard file in Visual studio (Version 7.4 (build 1033))

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am able to open the storyboard file in Xcode 9.2 but unable to open the file in Visual studio (Version 7.4 (build 1033))

Below is the log

**There was a problem parsing the XML in this document**

**Error Log:**

**System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse xml ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedViewController model, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00163] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:767 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000e3] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x00035] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x0012f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:382 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00050] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Scene scene, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x0009d] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:701 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000e3] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x00035] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x0012f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:382 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00050] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Storyboard sb, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00046] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:906 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Boolean skipImageGeneration) [0x0002a] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:225 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00001] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:214 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml, MonoTouch.Design.DeviceFamily targetRuntime, MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContext modelObjectContext) [0x00016] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:203 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+d__164.MoveNext () [0x001c0] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.129.1/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:414 
Contents of /Users/prashanttelangi/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/7.0/iOSDesigner.2018-03-15__12-59-58.log:
Commit: ce1c2b463f394d025915bbd9e92ec2f1d4ed4b9e
[2018-03-15 13:00:12.6] INFO: IPhoneDesignerSdkManager: Initializing the designer service
[2018-03-15 13:00:12.7] INFO: ENTERING sandbox: AndroidDesignerMac
[2018-03-15 13:00:12.7] INFO: LEAVING sandbox: AndroidDesignerMac**

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: does that happen for every .storyboard or a specific one?

Comment: Nope, only for a specific storyboard.

Comment: Okay, did you create this file using VS and added view controllers using XCode? or is it just an empty storyboard?

Comment: I usually add and design any views  in XCode and just assign id(outlet) in VS as it is much easier to design views in XCode. The storyboard was working file earlier, i have few VC's in it, but yesterday i added a new VC in Xcode and from then its giving me this error. I tried to revert back my storyboard but still the issue persists.

Comment: it seams like a bug in VS, but generally both VS and XCode use slightly different xml elements format (for instance where do  they declare outlets) that might sometimes lead to VS not being able to open it in VS or sometimes the app would crash with no exceptions presented

Comment: Can you load this Storyboard file in XCode?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Yes I can load the storyboard file in XCode

Answer (score 0):

I updated my **Visual Studio** version to **7.4.1 (build 48)** and voila this issues seems to be vanished.